# h5dump fails with "libhdf5_serial.so.100: cannot open shared object file"

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, hdf5

I am on Ubunto 18.04.  I installed libhdf5-serial-dev:

```
sudo apt-get install libhdf5-serial-dev
```

This installed ok - no errors.  I can compile, link, and run a C++ file ok that creates and populates an HDF5 file.  The resultant file looks good - I can read it ok with h5py and Python.

I installed hdf5-tools:

```
sudo apt-get install hdf5-tools
```

That also installed ok - no errors.  But when I run h5dump I get:

```
h5dump: error while loading shared libraries: libhdf5_serial.so.100: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

That file does not exist in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/hdf5/serial (or /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu).  No files with ".100" exist in either of those directories.

Any suggestions on what I've done wrong, and/or how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None of the answers I found on the web helped me solve this problem - I tried every suggestion I found.

In the end, updating to Ubuntu 20.04 fixed the problem.  Maybe reinstalling Ubuntu 18.04 would also have fixed the problem.